# Jquery slider attach with Mouse event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using jquery slider which working fine in chrome `browser`but when I run the same code in `firefox` then an event is attach with the mouse and when I move `either` left or `right` then It auto slide scroll.

So I want it functionality as like chrome. Can any 1 please help me that how  can I stop that hover effect from `firefox`

I am using the samve version of `jquery-min.js` and `jquery-ui.js` that is `1.11.1` and `jquery-ui.css` version `1.9.1`.

Any one's thought or review is much appreciated

I paste complete code below and also set [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/reLp8rw8/2/)

```
<html>
<head>

   <title>slider problem</title>

  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="" class="span12 sliderSpecific ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" aria-disabled="false">    <a class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" href="#" tabindex="-1" style="left: 0%;"></a></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.sliderSpecific').slider({
      animate: true,
      range: "min",
      step: parseInt(50),
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        alert(' slider is slide here');
      }
    });
  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this with Firefox.  I'm using the latest, v40.0.2.  What version are you using?  I can see nothing about your code, or the slider widget that would cause a hover event to be bound, let alone in Firefox only.

Comment: I am using version 35 and I also check on 38 too. I request you to first slide and after that click on ok which comes from alert then move your mouse either left or right without clicking any where I am sure u will see the bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to re-create the issue, but it's not a bug.  It's browser specific behavior related to how the `mouseup` event is processed.  Actually IE (edge) has the same behavior as Firefox.  Chrome seems to be the exception, but you can still simulate the same behavior in chrome.  I haven't tested Safari or any other browsers.  What this comes down to is the `slide` function is triggered on `mousedown`.  You have defined that function as raising an alert.  What typically is happening (I'm guessing) is that after the alert opens you are picking your finger up off the mouse button and clicking again on the `OK` button.  This causes the alert's message box to handle the `mouseup` event.  Chrome happens to handle it nicely, allowing the parent window (main browser window) to receive the `mouseup` event.  Apparently Firefox and IE do not.  Therefore, the page still thinks the mouse button is depressed, and thinks you're still trying to use the slider after you close the alert.

I think the fact that I can predict that you can simulate this in chrome is evidence that I understand the problem.  The way to simulate it in chrome is to click on the slider and start to drag it, but when the alert opens, do not release the mouse button, instead use the spacebar to "click the OK button".  After the alert closes, while still holding the mouse button down, move left to right and you'll see the same result that you saw in Firefox.  You're manually simulating the way Firefox is treating the mouse's state.

So how do you fix this?  Remove the alert, or put the alert on a timeout, which will allow the `mouseup` event to be handled before the alert message box gobbles it up...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // This block isn't necessary, just adding for completion in my example 
    var cnt = 0; // keeping a count for unique messages
    // just adding a container for non-blocking output messages
    $('body').append('<div id="output"></div>');
    // End unnecessary block ----------------------------------------------

    $('.sliderSpecific').slider({
      animate: true,
      range: "min",
      step: parseInt(50),
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        // Causes unexpected behavior in IE/Firefox 
        //alert(' slider is slide here'); 

        // Non-blocking output option...
        console.log(' slider is slide here');  
        // Another non-blocking output option...
        $('div#output').html(' slider is slide here (' + (cnt++).toString() + ')');

        // Workaround for using blocking output (alert/confirm)
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert('yay, on a delay works!');
        }, 0);
      }
    });
```

});